# Skeptical hypothesis as undecidable statement

Tags: logic, epistemology

Does anybody support the idea that the skeptical hypothesis (like the possibility that we are brains in a vat) is not assessable? By that I mean that the skeptical hypothesis may resemblance the sort of undecidable statements that troubles some formal systems.

Comment: This is an idea I associate with Gödel Escher Bach, but I can't remember if it was something clearly expressed or just hinted at.  Or maybe neither and I'm completely mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

I think Memming has the right idea.

The issue here isn't the skeptical or non-skeptical claim.  It's the entire domain of discourse.  The brain in a vat is a suggestion that can never be verified or debunked (even in theory).  It is -- quite literally -- nonsense.

It can get people to have an epiphany that they may not know their true nature, which can have an emotional impact and even transform the person.

But to try to argue it or treat it as if it has any information bearing properties is completely wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say he BIV hypothesis is non sense, it makes perfectly sense to me. I can't be it is true or false but I can understand it

Comment: @alessandro it's not nonsense in the pejorative term, but literally nonsense -- a claim about something outside our senses.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better terminology would be **[unfalsifiable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falsifiability) hypothesis**. It resembles undecidable statements in that they are usually constructed such that they are independent of science. (A + science) as well as (not A + science) would be a consistent belief of the world. I doubt there are deep connections.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a colourful way of referring to the notion that all there is - is minds; it's a way of questioning strict or naive realism.

Taken as a strictly descriptive statement it is obviously false.